# Datatables default number of records to display

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable, datatables

In dataTables I want to set an initial value to show in each page. How should I do this?

And then how to remove the length drop-down menu!

Comment: there is a drop down which allows you to set the quantity of the displayed records. I want to get rid of it (don't speak in Persian or they will report you)

Answer (score 0):

[iDisplayLength](http://datatables.net/usage/options#iDisplayLength) is the parameter you are looking for. Documentation is your friend:

to remove the pagination drop down use "[bLengthChange](https://www.datatables.net/ref#bLengthChange)":false